# Fetch a list of string from remote state

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a VPC module that has the following outputs.

```
$ tf output

dev_cp_subnet_ids = [
  tolist([
    "subnet-0cb8b0a98205082d8",
    "subnet-03964e7892b6a5336",
    "subnet-0917a9e6d87918c87",
  ]),
]
vpc_id = "vpc-06f3520baa1199f6b"
```

I want to use the above values in another module i.e. [terrafrom-eks](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks)

I first go ahead and declare the remote state config

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "vpc" {
  backend = "http"
  config = {
    address = "..."
   }
}
```

and then as part of the module call, do the following

```
module "eks" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"

  cluster_name    = "build"
  cluster_version = "1.22"

  cluster_endpoint_private_access = true
  cluster_endpoint_public_access  = true

  cluster_addons = {
    coredns = {}
    kube-proxy = {}
    vpc-cni = {}
  }

  vpc_id     = data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.outputs.vpc_id
  subnet_ids = data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.outputs.dev_cp_subnet_ids
```

`vpc_id` is successfully fetched as I can see it in a `tf plan`

```
        }
      + vpc_id                 = "vpc-06f3520baa1199f6b"
    }

Plan: 41 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

but for `dev_cp_subnet_ids`, I get the following error

```
│ Error: Invalid value for module argument
│ 
│   on main.tf line 24, in module "eks":
│   24:   subnet_ids = data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.outputs.dev_cp_subnet_ids
│ 
│ The given value is not suitable for child module variable "subnet_ids"
│ defined at .terraform/modules/eks/variables.tf:53,1-22: incorrect list
│ element type: string required.
```

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks#input_subnet_ids) for `subnet_ids`, its of type `list(string)`. My understanding is that the following output is in the format of list(string)

```
dev_cp_subnet_ids = [
  tolist([
    "subnet-0cb8b0a98205082d8",
    "subnet-03964e7892b6a5336",
    "subnet-0917a9e6d87918c87",
  ]),
]
```

or am I missing something here ?

Comment: You have a list inside a list. Modify this data source from `data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.outputs.dev_cp_subnet_ids` to `data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.outputs.dev_cp_subnet_ids[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression you showed at the end of your question has the following type:

```
tuple([list(string)])
```

That is: a single-element tuple whose element is itself a list of strings.

Because Terraform knows that `subnet_ids` expects a list of strings, it is first trying to automatically convert that to a list type, and producing a value of the following type as a result:

```
list(list(string))
```

Terraform then notices that the element type of this resulting list is `list(string)` rather than `string` as the argument requires, and so returns this error.

You can fix this by removing the outer brackets `[ .. ]` so that you are just directly assigning the `tolist` result, which will be a list of strings as expected:

```
dev_cp_subnet_ids = tolist([
  "subnet-0cb8b0a98205082d8",
  "subnet-03964e7892b6a5336",
  "subnet-0917a9e6d87918c87",
]),
```